# jQuery button hide/show rss feed toggle

Tags: jquery

Hi there I've been taking a look around SO and "le google" to try and figure out a way I can make my divs behave as buttons and toggle data to be default hidden and then be shown when you press the button.
The whole idea is I get ajax data back and it displays. But I want to choose which(if any) data is displayed. below is my current attempt and such a thing! :D
TL;DR - trying to create buttons using jquery that displays data for whichever button is pressed any help is appreciated

HTML:

```
<div class="container"> <span class="news">BBC News</span>
 <span class="news">Sky News</span>
 <span class="news">Guardian News</span>
 <span class="news">Channel4 News</span>

</div>
<div class="bbc">bbc</div>
<div class="sky">sky</div>
<div class="guardian">guardian</div>
<div class="channel4">channel4</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 60px;
}
.news {
    background-color: #ff8100;
    border: 2px #d1ec4c outset;
    padding: 1px 4px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.news:active {
    border-style: inset;
    background-color: #ff8100;
    padding: 2px 3px 0 5px;
    /*shift text 1px to the right and down*/
}

.bbc {

}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $content = $(".bbc").hide();
    $(".toggle").on("click", function(e){
        $(this).toggleClass("bbc");
        $content.slideToggle();
    });
});
```

And here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/a4tas9qu/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you a better alternative.

```js
$(function () {
  $(".tab").hide();
  $(".tab:first").show();
  $("a").click(function () {
    $(".tab").hide();
    $($(this).attr("href")).show();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 60px;
}
.news {
  background-color: #ff8100;
  border: 2px #d1ec4c outset;
  padding: 1px 4px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.news:active {
  border-style: inset;
  background-color: #ff8100;
  padding: 2px 3px 0 5px;
  /*shift text 1px to the right and down*/
}
.bbc {
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <a href="#bbc" class="news">BBC News</a>
  <a href="#sky" class="news">Sky News</a>
  <a href="#guardian" class="news">Guardian News</a>
  <a href="#channel4" class="news">Channel4 News</a>
</div>
<div class="tab" id="bbc">bbc</div>
<div class="tab" id="sky">sky</div>
<div class="tab" id="guardian">guardian</div>
<div class="tab" id="channel4">channel4</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the response ! I've had a play around with this and it's pretty cool, is there a way to make this code run so it originally doesn't show anything ? like since it defaults to bbc shown ?

Comment: Yes, you can remove the rd line in the script. @DavingtonIII.